# redirect to a specific view from method controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, view, controller

I have a controller called "products_controllers.rb" that have this method:

```
def create
  ...
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.save
     ???????
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

Whenever the product is save I want to redirect it to an specific view called "suppliers", that belongs to the product views, how can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using restful routes and there is a relationship where product has many suppliers, you could use:

```
format.html { redirect_to product_suppliers_url(@product) }
```

with something like this in your routes.rb:

```
map.resource :products do |product|
  product.resource :suppliers
end
```

or you could also just use this:

```
format.html { redirect_to :action => 'suppliers', :id => @product.id }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like 
`redirect_to 'product/suppliers'`

Source:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect_to

Comment: Next time make sure to specify "in rails" in the text of your question since views and controllers are used by many frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
def create
  ...
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.save
     ???????
    else
      format.html { render :action => "suppliers" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end

def suppliers
  #Your suppliers code goes here
end
```

In routes.rb

```
resources :venues do
  member do
    get 'suppliers'
  end
end
```